# How to refresh page cache type in magento2

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I updated price by raw sql queries.but its not reflecting in front end.but its reflecting admin side.
If i refresh page cache then its reflecting in the front end.

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);
```

and my code to update price:

```
 $query= "SELECT entity_type_id  FROM ".$this->getTable('eav_entity_type')." WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'";
        $entityTypeId = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($query);
        $query= "SELECT attribute_id FROM ".$this->getTable('eav_attribute')." WHERE entity_type_id = '".$entityTypeId."' AND attribute_code = 'price'";
        $attributeId = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($query);
        if(count($Data)){
            foreach($Data as $key=>$value){
                $query= "SELECT entity_id  FROM ".$this->getTable('catalog_product_entity')." WHERE sku = '".$key."'";
                $entityId = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($query);
                 if($entityId)
                 $this->getConnection()->query("UPDATE ".$this->getTable('catalog_product_entity_decimal')." SET value='".$value."' WHERE attribute_id='".$attributeId."' AND entity_id='".$entityId."'");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over the CLI you can do the following

```
cache:clean
cache:disable
cache:enable
cache:flush
cache:status
```

To flush a specific cache type - for example full_page - run the following from the magento root in your CLI:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush full_page
```

to flush all caches:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

To see available types, do:

```
php bin/magento cache:status
```

To do it in the code, you need to use

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager;

public function __construct(
    Manager $cacheManager
) {
    parent::__construct($cacheManager);
}
```

and do:

```
$this->cacheManager->flush($cacheTypes);
```

Please see

```
/vendor/magento/module-backend/Console/Command/AbstractCacheTypeManageCommand.php
```

and

```
/vendor/magento/module-backend/Console/Command/CacheFlushCommand.php
```

Comment: i need in php script.it should not be manual.

Comment: Ok, you should have mentioned that =). I've edited my answer.