# Is it possible to refresh the varnish cache programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, varnish

I am looking for code that can clear varnish cache in Magento2. Need in the PHP script. It should not be manual.

Comment: `service varnish restart`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh page cache type in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102522/how-to-refresh-page-cache-type-in-magento2)

Comment: Thanks, But I need a PHP script to clear varnish cache.

Comment: if you dont know magento, varnish and php, there is no point to ask this kind of questions, because you wont be able to adequately test it and verify it works properly...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215617/how-to-send-a-purge-request-in-varnish